# Why is the Convention badge so named?

Tags: discussion, badges, wording

What does the word "convention" connote in the context of the [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/901/convention) badge?

The description of "10 posts with a score of 2 on meta" is unambiguous, but the choice of name isn't clear to me.

Comment: I know voting is different on meta, but I'm a little baffled by the downvote on this question.

Answer (score 6):

Well if you look at the [definition of *convention*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/convention):

> ### con·ven·tion [kuhn-ven-shuhn]
>
> ***noun***
>
> 1. a meeting or formal assembly, as of representatives or delegates, for discussion of and action on particular matters of common concern.
> 2. *U.S. Politics.* a representative party assembly to nominate candidates and adopt platforms and party rules.
> 3. an agreement, compact, or contract.
> 4. an international agreement, especially one dealing with a specific matter, as postal service or copyright.
> 5. a rule, method, or practice established by usage; custom: the convention of showing north at the top of a map.

It's basically describing the community. Posting things on meta is a way of contributing your ideas to the community, such as debating a topic, or whatever the case may be. By receiving 2 upvotes on 10 of your posts, you're also showing a sense of agreement among the community.

Similarly, check the [definition of *quorum*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quorum):

> ### quo·rum [kwawr-uhm, kwohr-]
>
> ***noun***
>
> 1. the number of members of a group or organization required to be present to transact business legally, usually a majority.
> 2. a particularly chosen group.

I think this one makes less sense than that of Convention...

Comment: I had the same idea as you suggest, but it seemed vague, so I thought maybe I'm just completely missing something. I agree about the Quorum badge.